# How to split date from string from server response in android?

Tags: android

I have a string like "2017-05-22 12:57:46.688" from which I have to separate date and want to change it's format like "dd/MM/yyyy"and set it to a textview.

Code is as below:

```
String transactionDate = post.getString(CEarningHistory.TRANSACTION_CTS);
String[] parts = transactionDate.split(" ");
SimpleDateFormat input = new SimpleDateFormat(parts[0]);
```

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` should be used to **parse** the string, ideally

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14999506/convert-string-date-to-string-date-different-format or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503527/how-do-i-convert-the-date-from-one-format-to-another-date-object-in-another-form

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17192776/get-value-of-day-month-form-date-object-in-android check this one

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37157034/4336740

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 SimpleDateFormat webFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
  webFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

 SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
  dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
String newDate =   dateFormat.format(webFormat.parse("YourdateinWebFormat"));
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this way, you need to pass server date time format and output format.

```
String yourDate = formatDateForString(inputFormat, outputFormat, inputDateTime);

public String formatDateForString(String inputFormat, String outputFormat, String inputDate) {

        Date parsed;
        String outputDate = "";

        SimpleDateFormat df_input = new SimpleDateFormat(inputFormat);

        SimpleDateFormat df_output = new SimpleDateFormat(outputFormat);

        try {
            parsed = df_input.parse(inputDate);
            outputDate = df_output.format(parsed);

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            LOGE("DateTime", "ParseException - dateFormat");
        }

        return outputDate.toUpperCase().replace(".","");

    }
```